# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to join two dataframe in Pyspark, here are tables details:

```
df1.count(): 9989352358(2 columns)
df2.count(): 64000000(1 columns)
```

Now every time when I join them I can in Spark UI that out of 1000 task 1 task is always failing and sometimes it's giving `GC overhead limit exceeded` sometimes it's giving `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` and sometimes `heartbeat timeout`.

But I got this in logs which I find it main reason:

```
23/03/28 07:10:13 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: mem size 134387820 > 134217728: flushing 4840100 records to disk.
23/03/28 07:10:13 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 133711235
23/03/28 07:10:30 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: mem size 134319884 > 134217728: flushing 4900100 records to disk.
23/03/28 07:10:30 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 134321506
23/03/28 07:10:45 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: mem size 134362428 > 134217728: flushing 4800100 records to disk.
23/03/28 07:10:45 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 133932237
23/03/28 07:10:52 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: mem size 134568280 > 134217728: flushing 4820100 records to disk.
23/03/28 07:10:52 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 133781816
23/03/28 07:11:00 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: mem size 134445336 > 134217728: flushing 4920100 records to disk.
23/03/28 07:11:00 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 134417873
23/03/28 07:11:08 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: mem size 134452136 > 134217728: flushing 4870100 records to disk.
23/03/28 07:11:08 INFO org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter: Flushing mem columnStore to file. allocated memory: 134350885
```

I feel like I'm runnig out of memory but I think I have given enough resources to my spark job. Here's my spark config:

```
park_config["spark.executor.memory"] = "16G"
spark_config["spark.executor.memoryOverhead"] = "8G"
spark_config["spark.executor.cores"] = "8"
spark_config["spark.driver.memory"] = "10G"
spark_config["spark.network.timeout"] = "20000s"
spark_config["spark.executor.heartbeatInterval"] = "1000000"
spark_config["spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled"] = "true"
spark_config["spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled"] = "true"
spark_config["spark.shuffle.service.enabled"] = "true"
spark_config["spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors"] = "200"
spark_config["spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors"] = "250"
```

I have tried so may things but nothing is working out, can someone tell me what might be the real reason and how can I update it to make it work. I have tried repartitioning as well but that didn't help as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're possibly bouncing onto a data skew problem if you're always having 1 task that fails when joining.

In that case, what is happening is the following:

- you want to join `df1` and `df2`
- the executors shuffle both datasets around
- one executor receives (because of skewed data) a very large amount of data. For example, you're joining on a column `country` and 50% of your data has as value `country` == `Brazil`. So 50% of your data will be sent to 1 executor for your join. The rest of the tasks might have nicely distributed values.
- then, that single executor tries to read in all of that data and fails because it is doing so much garbage collection because the size of the data is so large w.r.t. its memory.

**What I would do**

- Try to identify whether you have data skew (something like `df1.groupBy(joinCol).count()`)
- If you have data skew, use techniques like [salting](https://medium.com/curious-data-catalog/sparks-salting-a-step-towards-mitigating-skew-problem-5b2e66791620) to overcome this issue.